# Why Does this not work trying change DateSeparator

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

```
System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
result := StrToDateTime(Trim(val));
System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.DateSeparator := '/';
```

val Before = '10-23-2008 11:43:54'

Result After = 10/23/2008 11:43:54 AM

Clearly the `DateSeparator` was not set. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `DateSeparator` before calling `StrToDateTime()` (FYI, you should be using the `TFormatSettings` overloaded version of `StrToDateTime()`, not using the global `System.SysUtils.FormatSettings` variable at all). Clearly the `DateSeparator` did take effect to produce the `Result` you have shown.

Your `Result` is a `TDateTime`, not a `String`. If you are evaluating the `Result` in the debugger, then setting the RTL's formatting variables at runtime has no effect on the debugger. If you are evaluating the `Result` some other way, you did not show/explain how.